# Finding defects in wall paint (finding difference in textures)

Tags: image-processing, filters, opencv, edge-detection, texture

I have been experimenting with computer vision techniques to find defects in paintings, more specifically defective brush strokes. I have tried a handful of techniques such as different filters, One class ML classifiers. image subtraction etc. The problem seems to be the orange-peel kind of textural noise in the image (present even in perfectly painted ones). Any idea how to go about finding the defected brush strokes and highlighting them? Pictures attached for reference

[image: Defective wall paint][image: Perfectly painted wall]

Comment: I'd argue the rows of the lower picture aren't as highly correlated as the rows of the upper picture. I assume you've looked at basic techniques like autocorrelation, inter-row correlation before firing the ML cannon at the problem?

Comment: I haven't tried autocorrelation or inter-row correlation, but would it work every time as the brush strokes might be different each time?

Comment: yes, because you're not comparing to a "prototype" brush, but to the row above.

Comment: I'll give that a try and let you know if it worked!

Comment: The first image is definitely much more periodic than the second. I'd also suggest that this periodicity would show up very intenesely in the frequency domain.

Comment: @A_A Not sure if periodicity would help because the brush strokes might look completely random in a different picture and not necessarily follow a pattern

Comment: If the brushstrokes are still visible (compared to the second image), that would show up as a distinct pattern in the DFT. Do you have any representative images from that case?